# Fetch row-index and write it into dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes that have the following structure.

#### DF1

```
.... |                    Time                    | Site | AA | BB | CC |    
  58  | 20-04-2019 08:00:00 - 21-04-2019 08:00:00 | AR25 |  1 | NS | 93 |  
  59  | 21-04-1019 08:00:00 - 22-04-2019 08:00:00 | DP88 | NS |    | 3  |  
  60  | 21-04-1019 08:00:00 - 22-04-2019 08:00:00 | DP88 |    |  1 | 15 |
```

#### DF2

```
.... |     Time            | Error | Site |     
  10 | 20-04-2019 09:25:15 | 401   | AR25 |  
  11 | 20-04-2019 11:00:10 | 401   | AR25 |    
  15 | 21-04-2019 23:25:16 | 404   | DP88 |
```

The AA, BB, CC columns store some measured info about each site and can contain numeric values or be empty. Records in AA, BB, CC can depend on the date and site. So basically my steps are:
    1. Fetch rows in DF1 that have records in AA(then BB, then CC);
    2. Use the time interval and site name as keys for finding rows in DF2
    3. Put the index(indices) of the row from DF1 in the correspondent AA/BB/CC column in DF3 with the time, error and site records that matched the provided time interval and site name.

#### Resulting DF3 expected to be achieved

```
.... |  Time               | Error |Site |    AA   |   BB   |   CC  |    
  1  | 20-04-2019 09:25:15 |  401  |AR25 |  58     |        |    58 |  
  2  | 20-04-2019 11:00:10 |  401  |AR25 |  58     | 58     |       |  
  2  | 21-04-2019 23:25:16 |  404  |DP88 |  59,60  |  59,60 | 59,60 |
```

For the ease of use, I splitted the Time column in DF1 into two columns - Start and End

```py
df1['Start'] = df1['Time'].str.split(' - ').str[0]
df1['End'] = df1['Time'].str.split(' - ').str[1]
df1['Start'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Start'])
df1['End'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['End'])

cols = ['AA','BB', 'CC']
for column in df1[cols]:
    df1 = df1[(df1[column]!= 'NS') & (df1[column] != '0')]
    for name in df1['Site'].unique():
        if df2['Site'].str.contains(name) & df2['Time'].between(df1['Start'].values[0],df2['End'].values[0]):
            values = df1.index.values.tolist()
            df3[column] = [values]
```

It goes ok with the steps 1 and 2, but I can do nothing with the step 3. The problem is I can't get how to fetch indices to build the df3 with the structure I want, as there can be repetitive and multiple indices for each AA,BB,CC column.

Is it possible to achieve the expected result? If yes, need some clues what I need to do.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need those rows in which `df1['Time'] == df2['Time'] and df1['Site'] == df2['Site']`?

Comment: Can you explian mor elogic for add columns? Because e.g. in final in `BB` is no value, why?

Comment: @jezrael edited the post. Not every sites can have records in AA-CC columns. For example, site1 can have AA and CC data, site2 - only BB, site 3 - records in all three columns

Comment: @ShanAli kind of. df1['Time'] has a time interval record, while df2['Time'] - exact time. So df2['Time'] must fall in the time interval of df1['Time']. That's why actually I splitted df1['Time'] into Start and End.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
df1['Start'] = df1['Time'].str.split(' - ').str[0]
df1['End'] = df1['Time'].str.split(' - ').str[1]
df1['Start'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Start'])
df1['End'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['End'])
df2['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Time'])

#reset_index for avoid lost indices in both, merge together
df = df2.reset_index().merge(df1.reset_index(), on='Site', how='left', suffixes=('','_'))
#filter by condition
df = df[df['Time'].between(df['Start'],df['End'])]

cols = ['AA','BB','CC']
#filter values not matching - not sure if 0 number or 0 string, so added both
m = ~df[cols].isin(['NS', 0, '0'])
#get values from index to cols
df[cols] = m.astype(int).mul(df.pop('index_'), axis=0)

#join together with filter out `0` values
f = lambda x: ','.join(x[x!=0].astype(str))

c = df2.columns.tolist()
#aggregate join
df = df.groupby(['index'] + c)[cols].agg(f).reset_index(level=c)
print (df)
                     Time  Error  Site  AA     BB     CC
index                                                   
10    2019-04-20 09:25:15    401  AR25  58            58
11    2019-04-20 11:00:10    401  AR25  58            58
15    2019-04-21 23:25:16    404  DP88  60  59,60  59,60
```